# Visual Studio Code - display virtual directory path while debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a virtual directory on my localhost setup using IIS 10 that goes to a location formated like this...

```
http://vscode.dev/
```

Within Visual Studio Code, I can see when I press F5 on an my index.htm page, the debugging process begins.  I select Chrome.  I then see that my URL in my Chrome browser goes to something like this...

```
file:///C:/Users/my-name/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202015/VS%20Projects/VSCode/sandbox/index.htm
```

This is all being produced in Visual Studio Code from the launch.json page...

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch current file",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            //"file": "${workspaceRoot}/${file}"
           "file" : "${file}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch localhost with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/mypage.html",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "wwwroot"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222
        }
    ]
}
```

So here is my question....from this page, can I replace part of the path of `${file}`, like we do in JavaScript with replace() method?  Something like...

```
${file}.replace{'file:///C:/Users/my-name/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202015/VS%20Projects/VSCode/sandbox/':'http://vscode.dev/'}
```

...this way whenever I debug my .htm pages, it goes to a cleaner URL path? like this....

```
http://vscode.dev/index.htm
```

And if I'm off and there is a more efficient way in achieving my goal, I would appreciate that route as well.  Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.  Right before debugging in Visual Studio Code,  I then went back into launch.json file and replace the file: field under "Launch index.html" with...

```
"url": "http://vscode.dev/${fileBasename}"
```

So whenever I click F5, I get the following path in my Chrome browser...

```
http://vscode.dev/index.htm
```

What I love about this, is that this process is unique for every Visual Studio Code folder you work in, and Visual Studio Code remembers where to launch!

FYI - Visual Studio Code variable substitutions can be found here - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks. Also, you may need to listen for an available port on your Windows machine while doing this process.   and add that port value to your launch.json file.